# Как мобильное меню bootstrap научить открываться справа?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, menu, bootstrap4

Есть меню `bootstrap 4` в мобильной версии которого хочу открывать меню не стандартно сверху, а оно должно выезжать справа с перекрытием контента как [здесь](https://fitodac.github.io/bsnav/navbar-right.html)

Есть для этого примера [инструкция для подключения библиотеки Off-canvas](https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Off-Canvas-Bootstrap-4-Nav.html) специально для `Bootstrap 4`, делаю все по ней, но почему-то не работает..
Что не так?

Код и [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/ox9wn4kz/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/fitodac/bsnav/master/dist/bsnav.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fitodac/bsnav/master/dist/bsnav.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bsnav">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-spring"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-sm-end">
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-mobile mr-0">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/">Gallery</a></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по примеру, то там добавляется небольшой `html` код и `css` для него:

```
  <div class="bsnav-mobile">
    <div class="bsnav-mobile-overlay"></div>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
  </div>
```

Весь код:

```css
.bsnav-mobile, .bsnav-mobile .bsnav-mobile-overlay, .bsnav-sticky.navbar-fade, .bsnav-sticky.navbar-slide {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}


.bsnav-mobile {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 49;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.bsnav-mobile .navbar {
    background: #ccc !important; /* для наглядности */
  
    width: 230px;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
    flex-flow: column;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    overflow: auto;
}

.bsnav-mobile.in .navbar {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/fitodac/bsnav/master/dist/bsnav.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fitodac/bsnav/master/dist/bsnav.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bsnav"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">bsnav</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-spring"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-sm-end">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-mobile mr-0">
        <li class="nav-item nav-item-fill active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-item-fill"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-item-fill"><a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-item-fill"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item nav-item-fill"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bsnav-mobile">
    <div class="bsnav-mobile-overlay"></div>
    <div class="navbar"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: аа, вот оно что! Спасибо!